# How to fix Ionic cordova document-scanner showing low memory exception

Tags: angular, opencv, cordova, ionic-framework

**Ionic cordova** document scanner plugin just works fine for my requirement but most of the times it shows low memory exception

Please find the image attached[image]

can anyone please help me resolve the issue?
is there any memory optimization that I can do while building or generating the apk?

If not is there any alternative to cordova document-scanner plugin
I am using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/document-scanner

Comment: try this "Remove platform android and run ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0" or "android 8.0 using android-targetSdkVersion: 29" or check "https://github.com/NeutrinosPlatform/cordova-plugin-document-scanner/issues/74"  link

Comment: Do we need to downgrade to version 8.0.0 for making this work? is there no other solution for this issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem By adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the application tag directly in the AndroidManifest.xml file generated by Cordova.

OR

Add the following to config.xml and see if the issue persists.

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
   <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the workaround! is there any other way such as adding the configuration in config.xml file? because everytime we generate a new build it will need us to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Yes, Please check, i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sandip for sharing, unfortunately this didn't solve my issue, I implemented this method previously also, but certainly this is a great try!